Copy values and formats with a BASIC-Script
I want to copy the values, the formats and all conditional formats from an LibreOffice-Calc worksheet-range (A1:H100) to another (new/empty) worksheet of the same workbook.
This is, what I do actually:
sub blatt_einfuegen

  oActiveSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
  oTabellen = ThisComponent.Sheets
  sNewSheetName=oActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName("C1").String
  
  
  ' Prüfen, ob eine Tabelle mit dem Namen des Strings aus Zelle C1 existiert.
  If NOT oTabellen.hasbyName(sNewSheetName) Then
    ' Tabelle mit dem Namene sNewSheetName existiert nicht, also wird sie eingefügt.
    oTabellen.insertNewByName (sNewSheetName, 3)
  End If
  
  DIM oStart as Object, oZiel as Object

  oStart = ThisComponent.sheets.getByName("Aktuell")     '<--- Blatt wo die Daten stehen
  oZiel = ThisComponent.sheets.getByName(sNewSheetName)  '<--- Blatt wohin die Daten kopiert werden sollen

  ' Zellinhalte übertragen
  Dim aDataArray()  
  aDataArray = oStart.getCellRangeByName("A1:H100").getDataArray
  oZiel.getCellRangeByName("A1:H100").setDataArray(aDataArray)
 
  ' Spaltenbreiten übertragen
  For j = 0 To 6
    oZiel.Columns.getByIndex(j).Width = oStart.Columns.getByIndex(j).Width
  Next j

  Call CopyFormatBetweenSheets(sNewSheetName)
  
End Sub

Sub CopyFormatBetweenSheets(sName$)
    Dim oSourceSheet As Object
    Dim oTargetSheet As Object
    Dim oSourceRange As Object
    Dim oTargetRange As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    ' Get the source sheet (where the source range is located)
    oSourceSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("Aktuell")
    
    ' Get the target sheet (where the target range is located)
    oTargetSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName(sName)    
    
    ' Define the source range (range with the formatting to be copied)
    oSourceRange = oSourceSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:H100")
    
    ' Define the target range (range where the formatting will be applied)
    oTargetRange = oTargetSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:H100")

    ' Copy the formatting from the source range to the target range
    For i = 0 To oSourceRange.Rows.getCount() - 1
       For j = 0 To oSourceRange.Columns.getCount() - 1
            oTargetRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).CharFontName = oSourceRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).CharFontName
            oTargetRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).CharHeight = oSourceRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).CharHeight
            oTargetRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).CharWeight = oSourceRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).CharWeight
            oTargetRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).NumberFormat = oSourceRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).NumberFormat
            oTargetRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).CharUnderline = oSourceRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).CharUnderline
            oTargetRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).HoriJustify = oSourceRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).HoriJustify
            oTargetRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).VertJustify = oSourceRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).VertJustify
            oTargetRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).ConditionalFormat = oSourceRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).ConditionalFormat

            ' Add more properties as needed (e.g., CharColor, CellBackColor, etc.)
       Next j
    Next i
End Sub

It copies the values, the formats, but only the first conditional format, what is defined in the cells from oSourceRange.
Is it possible to copy all of the conditional formats of the cells or is there a better way for copying the oSourceRange values, formats and conditional formats to the oTargetRange?
The values are copyied by an array-method (.setDataArray) -  Is there a method for doing this with the fomats?

I found another answer using direct copy method. However, this only works within the same document, which was your requirement so it's OK.
sub blatt_einfuegen
    oActiveSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    oTabellen = ThisComponent.Sheets
    sNewSheetName=oActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName("C1").String
    ' Prüfen, ob eine Tabelle mit dem Namen des Strings aus Zelle C1 existiert.
    If NOT oTabellen.hasbyName(sNewSheetName) Then
        ' Tabelle mit dem Namene sNewSheetName existiert nicht, also wird sie eingefügt.
        oTabellen.insertNewByName (sNewSheetName, 3)
    End If
    DIM oStart as Object, oZiel as Object

    CopyCells("Aktuell", sNewSheetName)
  
End Sub

sub CopyCells(sinSource$, sinDest$)
    rem --------------------------------------------------------------
    dim oFromSheet as object
    dim oToSheet as object
    dim oCell as object
    dim oCellRange as object
    dim oCellRangeAddr as object
    dim oCols as object
    rem --------------------------------------------------------------
    oFromSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName(sinSource)
    oToSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName(sinDest)

    rem Select the region to copy
    oCellRange = oFromSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:H100")
    oCellRangeAddr = oCellRange.getRangeAddress()
  
    rem Get the address of the destination
    oCell = oToSheet.getCellByPosition(0,0).getCellAddress()
    
    rem Execute the copy
    oToSheet.copyRange(oCell, oCellRangeAddr)
    
    rem Copy column width
    Dim lCol as long
    For lCol = 0 to oCellRange.Columns.getCount() - 1
        oToSheet.Columns(lCol).Width = oFromSheet.Columns(lCol).Width
    Next lCol
    
end sub


Perfect! It works for me. Thank you so much.
How do I get the columns width to have the same width for all columns A to H in oToSheet like in oFromSheet?

Column width isn't copied even when you copy cells manually. Column width is set at the  column level. I have updated the code to include a section that copies the column width. Thanks for marking the answer, I appreciate that.

If you don't mind copying everything in those source cells, then you can use the dispatch to do all the work for you.
sub blatt_einfuegen
    oActiveSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    oTabellen = ThisComponent.Sheets
    sNewSheetName=oActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName("C1").String
    ' Prüfen, ob eine Tabelle mit dem Namen des Strings aus Zelle C1 existiert.
    If NOT oTabellen.hasbyName(sNewSheetName) Then
        ' Tabelle mit dem Namene sNewSheetName existiert nicht, also wird sie eingefügt.
        oTabellen.insertNewByName (sNewSheetName, 3)
    End If
    DIM oStart as Object, oZiel as Object

    CopyCells("Aktuell", sNewSheetName)
  
End Sub

sub CopyCells(sinSource$, sinDest$)
    rem --------------------------------------------------------------
    rem define variables
    dim oDoc   as object
    dim oFrame as object
    dim oDispatcher as object
    dim oFromSheet as object
    dim oToSheet as object
    dim oCell as object
    dim oCellRange as object
    rem --------------------------------------------------------------
    rem get access to the oDoc
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oFrame = oDoc.CurrentController.Frame
    oDispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
    oFromSheet = oDoc.Sheets.getByName(sinSource)
    oToSheet = oDoc.Sheets.getByName(sinDest)

    rem Select the region to copy
    oCellRange = oFromSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:H100")
    oDoc.getCurrentController().Select(oCellRange)  
    oDispatcher.executeDispatch(oFrame, ".uno:Copy", "", 0, Array())

    rem Goto the sheet and cell to paste into
    oCell = oToSheet.getCellByPosition(0,0)
    oDoc.getCurrentController().Select(oCell)   
    oDispatcher.executeDispatch(oFrame, ".uno:Paste", "", 0, Array())

end sub

2024/05/16 edit: updated so would work with the original first sub.

I used your script in combination with my first script (Call blatt_einfuegen (sNewSheetName), but it inserts the values from the systems clipboard, beginning in cell "A1".

Updated the code to include the first sub (it needs to be changed too to work with the copy). Now simply copy both subs and replace your subs to work. Would appreciate the "Answer" vote if it works for you.

Your last script did not work for me. A new sheet was created, but no values from oFromSheet to oToSheet were copied.

Did you use it on a sheet where C1 is the name of the new sheet? Also, did you have a sheet named Aktuell? These were the requirements in your original script.

Yes, the name of the new sheet is the value (string) in Cell C1 of sheet "Aktuell". If I run this script, a new sheet named with the value of cell C1 is created and the content of my (system) clipboard is inserted in cell A1 of the new sheet.

According to your original code, what you said is NOT how it works. The name of the new sheet is in the C1 cell of the CURRENT sheet where you run the macro. The data is copied from A1:H100 in Aktuell sheet. Question: are you running in headless mode or with Calc open?

Also, did you update the code with the new blatt_einfuegen I provided?

Yes, I deleted all my own macros' code in my document and inserted your provided code without changing it. I have a button in my sheet named Aktuell which action is to start the macro blatt_einfuegen. And no, I'm not running my LibreOffice Calc headless.

I am stumped as to what went wrong... Can you upload your file somewhere, then provide a link for me to download and test out directly (with any private information removed of course)?
Also what version of LO and OS are you using?

I was able to reproduce your problem when executing the macro from the button. Unfortunately, it seems the frame controller isn't too reliable in getting the sheet info. I was able to find a direct method of copying that seem to work in a new answer below.
